# Content of the result of aggregation query not returned

Tags: java, android

I am a begineer and I want to allow just one user to sign up as per the demand of my project.
The SIGNUP.java is meant to accomplish it using DbHelper.java but things work fine for
c.getCount()
but not for 
Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0))

SIGNUP.java reads:

```
package com.bishal.android.taskmanager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SIGNUP extends Activity {
    Button register;
    private EditText etName;
    private EditText etEmail;
    //private EditText etUsername;
    private EditText etPassword;
    private DbHelper dbhelper;

     AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);
        dbhelper=new DbHelper(this);
        etName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        etEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_email);
        etPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_signup_password);
        register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
        final boolean bregister=(dbhelper.NoOfUser()==0)?true:false;
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //String UserNameValue=etUsername.getText().toString();
                String NameValue=etName.getText().toString();
                String EmailValue=etEmail.getText().toString();
                String PasswordValue=etPassword.getText().toString();

                //Toast.makeText(SIGNUP.this,dbhelper.ThereIsUser(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (bregister){
                ACCOUNT_INFO account=new ACCOUNT_INFO(NameValue,EmailValue,PasswordValue);
                if(NameValue.trim().length()>0 && EmailValue.trim().length() > 0 &&  PasswordValue.trim().length() >0){ 
                if(dbhelper.eMailValidation(EmailValue)){
                    if(dbhelper.validateregister(EmailValue)){
                    dbhelper.addAccount(account);
                    Toast.makeText(SIGNUP.this, "Your account has been sucessfully created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else{
                    alert.showAlertDialog(SIGNUP.this, "Signup failed..", "Username/Email already exists.", false);
                }
            }
                else{
                    alert.showAlertDialog(SIGNUP.this,"Signup failed..", "Email address is not in such form.", false);
                }
        }
            else{
                alert.showAlertDialog(SIGNUP.this, "Signup failed..", "Please enter empty fields.", false);
            }
        }
    }
});

}

}
```

DbHelper.java reads(why 'count' is not returned as count of number of rows in table?):

```
    package com.bishal.android.taskmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
//import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String TAG=DbHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DB_NAME="Store Account.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION=1;
    public static final String TABLE="Account_Info";
    public static final String COL_ID="Id";   //special for ID
    public static final String COL_NAME="Name";
    public static final String COL_EMAIL="Email";
    //public static final String COL_UNAME="Username";
    public static final String COL_PASSWORD="Password";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String CREATE_ACCOUNT_INFORMATION = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "("
                + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_NAME + " String,"
                 + COL_EMAIL + " String," + COL_PASSWORD + " String" + ")";

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+CREATE_ACCOUNT_INFORMATION);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ACCOUNT_INFORMATION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exists " + TABLE);
        Log.d(TAG,"onUpdate dropped table "+ TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    void addAccount(ACCOUNT_INFO account){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_NAME,account.getNAME());
        values.put(COL_EMAIL,account.getEMAIL());
        //values.put(COL_UNAME, account.getUSERNAME());
        values.put(COL_PASSWORD, account.getPASSWORD());
        db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
        db.close();
    }



    public boolean validateuser(String email,String password){
        Cursor c=getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE "
                + COL_EMAIL + "='" + email +"'AND "+COL_PASSWORD+"='" + password+"'" ,  null);
        if(c.getCount()>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public boolean validateregister(String email){
        Cursor c=getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE "
                + COL_EMAIL + "='" + email+"'" ,  null);
        if(c.getCount()>0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean eMailValidation(String emailValue) {
        final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
                "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);;
        Matcher matcher;
        matcher = pattern.matcher(emailValue);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    public int NoOfUser() {
        Cursor c=getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM " + TABLE, null);
        int count=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should get in the habit of using `host variables` on your SQL statements. `"select * from tbl where col1=? and col2=?", new String[] { col1_val, col2_val }`. This will help keep you safe from Sql Injection attacks, etc.

Comment: in your function `validateuser()` the query string needs to have a space (" ") after the variable `email` and the word `AND`. not sure how it parsed correctly the way it is. switch to using host variables and this problem goes away.